# PHP and MySQL content displaying out of order

Tags: php, mysql, html, dynamic

While dynamically generating a page with different types of contents , the "post" content is appearing above the static content which is being generated.I want it the other way around. Does there appear to be anything in my code that would make this happen, or do you think the problem has something to do with my database? Thanks.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE pages LIKE '%$pageID%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

// Display pages's static content

if ($row['type'] == "static") {

    echo "
        <h2>" . $row['tile'] . "</h2>
        <content>" . $row['body'] . "</content>
    ";
}

// Display pages's posts

else {
    echo "
        <h2>" . $row['tile'] . "</h2>
        <content>" . $row['body'] . "</content>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Add a separator between types.Check if your $row['type'] is a correct variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE pages LIKE '%$pageID%' ORDER BY type desc
```

Comment: Perfect. Nice and easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 'static' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: THANK YOU, that did the trick! I wasted hours stressing over this one. Any chance you could explain to me what that code does exactly? Looks like I need to learn MySQL better.

Comment: Sure. `ORDER BY [somecolumn]` will order the results by the column you pass. Instead of passing a column, I'm passing a conditional expression (`CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END`), to force rows where the `type` equals `'static'` to be returned first (`0`).